# is SOP(sentence order prediction) implemented?

Tags: huggingface-transformers

I am reviewing huggingface's version of Albert.

However, I cannot find any code or comment about SOP.

I can find NSP(Next Sentence Prediction) implementation from modeling_from [src/transformers/modeling_bert.py](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/master/src/transformers/modeling_bert.py).

```
if masked_lm_labels is not None and next_sentence_label is not None:
    loss_fct = CrossEntropyLoss()
    masked_lm_loss = loss_fct(prediction_scores.view(-1, self.config.vocab_size), masked_lm_labels.view(-1))
    next_sentence_loss = loss_fct(seq_relationship_score.view(-1, 2), next_sentence_label.view(-1))
    total_loss = masked_lm_loss + next_sentence_loss
    outputs = (total_loss,) + outputs
```

Is SOP inherited from here with SOP-style labeling? or Is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

The sentence order loss is [here](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/master/src/transformers/models/albert/modeling_tf_albert.py#L107):

```
sentence_order_loss = loss_fn(y_true=sentence_order_label, y_pred=sentence_order_reduced_logits)
```

It's just a cross entropy loss.